# Did human computers use floating-point arithmetics?

Tags: ho.history-overview, na.numerical-analysis

Before the proliferation of computers in the 1950s, did human computers use floating-point formats for their computations?

Floating-point calculation was reportedly implemented already in the 1910s ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#History)), so one might assume the idea must have been in circulation way earlier than that. However, I haven't found any information how people were computing back then. Since most human computer work must have been numerical, they may have used floating-point calculations.

Comment: Human floating point is usually called *exponential* or *scientific notation*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation , and it was certainly used before computing machines. Numerical calculations were largely done with the help of logarithmic and trigonometric tables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table .

Comment: Humans used slide rules long before the 1950s, and a slide rule calculates without any decimal point at all.

Comment: In addition, the notion of [_significant figures_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) is somewhat relevant here, as a 'floating point' means of tracking error that was used long before digital computers were in use.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: *very* relevant in fact: digital floating-point with a fixed width significand (aka mantissa) is exactly like rounding to a fixed number of significant figures after every step.  (Especially if you use [decimal floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Decimal), like IBM POWER CPUs support in hardware).  Digital floating-point has the same relative precision at every order of magnitude (except subnormals where you're only using part of the mantissa at the minimum exponent), which is just another way of describing the significant figures / fixed-width mantissa.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I am aware of those techniques, but what system did they use in 'mass computing', as done by human computers, before digital computers entered the scene?

Comment: @MartinSeysen A slide rule has a decimal point - carried in the associated neural memory. You know that :-). I was introduced to sliderules in 1964 - long long after their introduction. I acquired my first digital electronic calculator in 1974 and still used slide rules in earnest for a little while until calcuators overtook their functionality.

Comment: This would have been a better fit for hsm.SE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the field of hydrodynamics the first calculation by a human computer was carried out around 1920 for a [project](https://ilorentz.org/history/zuiderzee/zuiderzee.html) to transform an open sea into a closed lake, with the aim to protect Holland from flooding. The physicist Hendrik Lorentz headed a task force to calculate the effect of the dike on the tidal flow.

The human computer was the hydraulic engineer Jo Thijsse. Lorentz commented as follows on this work:

> The numerical calculations were so lengthy, that we came close to the
> ultimate limit of what can be done in this way. I myself had no part
> in this. I did try once or twice to set up and work out such a
> calculation, but then it would turn out that I had made a mistake, so
> that it had to be done all over again by others.

The hydrodynamic calculation involved quantities differing by many orders of magnitude, and so necessarily required floating point arithmetic. Here is one page from their report, showing the exponential notation.

[image]

Comment: That is interesting. Agreeing on a numerical standard becomes relevant when you need to manage huge amounts of computations (such as hundreds of matrix-vector products, for example). Do you happen to know what kind of computation this was (Linear systems, Newton method, ... )